# Pandas query throws error when column name starts with a number

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to perform a query on the following dataframe:

```
data = {'ab': [1,2,3], 'c1': [1,2,3], 'd': [1,2,3], 'e_f': [1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for cl in df.columns:
    print len(df.query('%s==2' %cl))
```

This works fine. However, if a column name starts with a number then it throws a syntax error.

```
data = {'ab': [1,2,3], 'c1': [1,2,3], '1d': [1,2,3], 'e_f': [1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for cl in df.columns:
    print len(df.query('%s==2' %cl))
```

File "", line 1

```
1 d ==2
  ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I think that the problem is related to the format of the string. I was wondering what will be the correct way to form this query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`query` uses `pandas.eval`, which is [documented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval) to "evaluate a Python expression as a string".  Your query is not a valid Python expression, because `1d` is not valid syntax in Python, so you can't use `query` to refer to this column that way.

Things in pandas are generally easier if you make sure all your columns are valid Python identifiers.

Answer (score -1):

You could always get a list of the column names which returns the columns as strings and then query them.

```
data = {'ab': [1,2,3], 'c1': [1,2,3], 'd': [1,2,3], 'e_f': [1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cols = list(df)
```

So for example `cols[0]` would be `'ab'` and `cols[2]` would be `'1d'`.