# Using query() when column names are numeric or contain special characters

Tags: python, pandas, numexpr

Is it possible to use the query method in pandas where columns don't have names or their name have special characters in it? I'd like to use the query string from a configuration file but for some columns this doesn't work. I am aware of the [valid Python identifiers limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27787349/1136458)  but I wonder if there is any other special keyword like index that I haven't seen

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3,4)))
>>>df['Special:chars'] = [1,2,9]
>>>df

   0  1  2  3  Special:chars
0  1  1  1  1              1
1  1  1  1  1              2
2  1  1  1  1              9

>>>df.query('index in [0,2]') #the only working query I was able to find

   0  1  2  3  Special:chars
0  1  1  1  1              1
2  1  1  1  1              9

>>>df.query('0<2')
KeyError: True

>>>df.query('"0"<2')
TypeError: data type "" not understood

>>>df.query('Special:chars >=2')
    Special :chars >=2
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>>df.query('"Special:chars" >=2')
data type "Special:chars" not understood
```

Comment: Is there some reason you are trying to do this with `query` specifically?  It's not really the obvious tool for this situation.  For example, you could just do `df.iloc[[0,2]]` to get rows 0 and 2.

Comment: I need to put the query in a config file as a string. Actually what I need to do is the last example ('Special:chars >= 2'). The dataframe comes from a csv file exported from an application (it wasn't me chosing to put a colon in the name of the column), so now I created other columns with a "sanitized" name in order to be use a query of it. I was wondering  if there was a way to keep the original name